# Хранение данных на SD карте

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, вот у меня есть основная папка mapData, в которой будут храниться данные для приложения, изображения добавленные пользователем, тхт файлы с текстом и тд. Я хочу, чтобы эта папка могла храниться как на внутренней памяти телефона, так и на внешней SD карте в корне, на выбор пользователя. Причем эта папка не должна удаляться вместе с приложением. Возможно ли так сделать?
Пока у меня даже не создается папка на SD карте, не могу понять как хотя бы ее создать.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    createFolder(); //создать папку
}



private void createFolder() {
    if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + /*File.separator +*/ "mapData");

        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
    }
}

public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        return true;
    }
}
```

В AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: при создании папки вам нужно добавить слеш к ее названию - "/mapData"

Comment: Папка создается в памяти телефона, а не на SD карте.. На SD карте вообще можно создавать каталоги и файлы? Я что-то и толковых примеров то не нашел в гугле..

Comment: Найти где у аппарата встроенная, а где внешняя - задача не для слабонервных и есть балалайки, на которых это в принципе невозможно. Поэтому советую предоставить юзеру абсолютную свободу выбора папки хранения, вместо выбора внешней/внутренней.

Comment: Так у него нет выбора, папка mapData создается на внутренней памяти телефона..

Comment: Я имею в виду выбор папки через встроенный в приложение проводник или [Платформу доступа к хранилищу (Storage Access Framework)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider?hl=RU) - то есть она будет располагаться (вы создадите) там, где выберет пользователь, а не обязательно в корне какого-то хранилища